# how to draw tic tac toe board as UIView in swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uibezierpath, tic-tac-toe

In my `UIViewController` I have a single subclass of `UIView` in which I will draw a tic tac toe board. Somehow the dividers (the "#" shape) I'm drawing using `UIBezierPath()` are not dividing the board evenly. Instead of 1/3-1/3-1/3, the vertical dividers are closer to 45%-45%-10% even though the dimensions printouts make sense. What am I missing? Thanks

In my subclass:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GameBoardView: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // set up gameBoard dimensions everytime drawRect() is called
        setUpGameBoardCells()
        self.frame = CGRectMake(gameBoardPosX, gameBoardPosY, gameBoardLength, gameBoardLength)
        print("gameBoard.frame: x=\(self.frame.origin.x), y=\(self.frame.origin.y), h=\(self.frame.height), w=\(self.frame.width)\n")

        // draw dividers & cells
        var divider = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: cellWidth, y: 0, width: dividerWidth, height: gameBoardLength))
        divider.lineWidth = 1
        UIColor.orangeColor().setStroke()
        divider.stroke()

        divider = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: cellWidth * 2 + dividerWidth, y: 0, width: dividerWidth, height: gameBoardLength))
        divider.stroke()
   }
}
```

And this is how I set up the dimensions to handle any sized screens:

```
var screenSize = CGRect()
let screenMargin: CGFloat = 20   // to the edge

var gameBoardIsPortrait = Bool()
var gameBoardLength = CGFloat()
var gameBoardPosX = CGFloat()
var gameBoardPosY = CGFloat()

let cellsPerRow: Int = 3
var cellWidth = CGFloat()
let dividerWidthGuide: CGFloat = 0.02   // guideline % of gameBoardLength
var dividerWidth = CGFloat()

let debugPrint = true

func setUpGameBoardCells() {

    screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    // gameBoard is a square
    gameBoardIsPortrait = (screenSize.height >= screenSize.width ? true : false)
    gameBoardLength = min(screenSize.height, screenSize.width) - screenMargin * 2
    gameBoardPosX = (screenSize.width - gameBoardLength) / 2
    gameBoardPosY = (screenSize.height - gameBoardLength) / 2

    // want cells & dividers on gameBoard to be whole numbers
    dividerWidth = round(gameBoardLength * dividerWidthGuide)
    let cellsTotalWidth: Int = Int(gameBoardLength) - Int(dividerWidth) * (cellsPerRow - 1)
    let dividerWidthFudge: CGFloat = (cellsTotalWidth % cellsPerRow == 1 ? -1 : (cellsTotalWidth % cellsPerRow == 2 ? 1 : 0))
    dividerWidth += dividerWidthFudge
    cellWidth = CGFloat((cellsTotalWidth - Int(dividerWidthFudge) * (cellsPerRow - 1)) / cellsPerRow)

    if debugPrint {
        print("setUpCellDivision()->\nscreen: h=\(screenSize.height), w=\(screenSize.width)")
        print("gameBoardIsPortrait=\(gameBoardIsPortrait), gameBoardLength=\(gameBoardLength), gameBoardPosX=\(gameBoardPosX), gameBoardPosY=\(gameBoardPosY)")
        print("cellWidth=\(cellWidth), dividerWidth=\(dividerWidth)\n")
    }
}
```

What is bizarre is that in xcode it looks right:

[image]

But in simulator it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the setting of the `frame` from within `drawRect`. This would especially be a problem if you have any auto-layout constraints defined for the view.

The laying out of a view and the drawing of that view are two different steps, and you should therefore separate that logic.

Personally, I'd set up auto-layout constraints on the view to make sure that it is square, centered, and had the correct spacing. Then the view rendering is simplified:

```
@IBDesignable class GameBoardView: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        setUpGameBoardCells()

        UIColor.orangeColor().setStroke()

        var divider = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: cellWidth, y: 0, width: dividerWidth, height: bounds.size.height))
        divider.lineWidth = 1
        divider.stroke()

        divider = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: cellWidth * 2 + dividerWidth, y: 0, width: dividerWidth, height: bounds.size.height))
        divider.lineWidth = 1
        divider.stroke()
    }

    let cellsPerRow = 3
    let dividerWidthGuide: CGFloat = 0.02   // guideline % of gameBoardLength

    var cellWidth: CGFloat!
    var cellHeight: CGFloat!
    var dividerWidth: CGFloat!

    func setUpGameBoardCells() {
        let gameBoardLength = min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width)
        dividerWidth = round(gameBoardLength * dividerWidthGuide)
        let cellsTotalWidth: Int = Int(gameBoardLength) - Int(dividerWidth) * (cellsPerRow - 1)
        let dividerWidthFudge: CGFloat = (cellsTotalWidth % cellsPerRow == 1 ? -1 : (cellsTotalWidth % cellsPerRow == 2 ? 1 : 0))
        dividerWidth! += dividerWidthFudge
        cellWidth = CGFloat((cellsTotalWidth - Int(dividerWidthFudge) * (cellsPerRow - 1)) / cellsPerRow)
    }

}
```

That yields:

[image]

Clearly, just repeat for your horizontal separators, too.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your response. I confirm by taking the CGRectMake() out of drawRect() the dividers now show up in the right places. If I still want to programmatically resize & move the board to a specific place, where should I put the CGRectMake() call? I have tried putting it in viewWillAppear() in my ViewController but that does not seem to work. Thanks

Comment: You configure the `frame` like you would any other view. If you're using auto layout and if you added it on a storyboard, just add outlets for the constraints and then you can adjust the `constant` property of the constraints as appropriate. The key is that if you're using auto layout, don't adjust the `frame` directly. Adjust the constraints.

Comment: Constraints! Of course. Thanks, Rob, I just got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be adding UIViews(as separator lines) on yellow UIView and constraint them properly. You don't have to write too much of code.I would suggest to avoid the code in such cases.

You can try this. Draw the lines by calculating the frame of the view. The following will resize according to the frame.

```
func drawRect(frame frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 52, y: 30, width: 90, height: 75)) {

    //// Bezier Drawing
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
    bezierPath.stroke()


    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: frame.minX + floor(frame.width * 0.32778) + 0.5, y: frame.minY + floor(frame.height * 0.06000) + 0.5, width: floor(frame.width * 0.35000) - floor(frame.width * 0.32778), height: floor(frame.height * 0.92667) - floor(frame.height * 0.06000)))
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1
    rectanglePath.stroke()


    //// Rectangle 3 Drawing
    let rectangle3Path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: frame.minX + floor(frame.width * 0.68333) + 0.5, y: frame.minY + floor(frame.height * 0.06000) + 0.5, width: floor(frame.width * 0.70556) - floor(frame.width * 0.68333), height: floor(frame.height * 0.92667) - floor(frame.height * 0.06000)))
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    rectangle3Path.lineWidth = 1
    rectangle3Path.stroke()


    //// Rectangle 5 Drawing
    let rectangle5Path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: frame.minX + floor(frame.width * 0.07222) + 0.5, y: frame.minY + floor(frame.height * 0.63333) + 0.5, width: floor(frame.width * 0.92778) - floor(frame.width * 0.07222), height: floor(frame.height * 0.66000) - floor(frame.height * 0.63333)))
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    rectangle5Path.lineWidth = 1
    rectangle5Path.stroke()


    //// Rectangle 6 Drawing
    let rectangle6Path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: frame.minX + floor(frame.width * 0.07222) + 0.5, y: frame.minY + floor(frame.height * 0.31333) + 0.5, width: floor(frame.width * 0.92778) - floor(frame.width * 0.07222), height: floor(frame.height * 0.34000) - floor(frame.height * 0.31333)))
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    rectangle6Path.lineWidth = 1
    rectangle6Path.stroke()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your constraints aren't set up correctly. Try redoing the constraints to see if that fixes things.

Comment: I intentionally did not add constraints since I'm resizing & repositioning the board programmatically.

Comment: oh right! My apologises, in that case try adding self before the screenSize